# Regex Search and Replace with Capture Group in CSS File

Tags: css, regex, bash, sed

I have a CSS file which includes a set of rules wrapped in a @critical rule containing critical styles whose content I want to extract for inlining:

```
@critical {

    .foo {
        ...
    }

    @media bar {
        ...
    }
}
```

I’m trying to do the extraction using `sed` search and replace with the following regex (I’m on a Mac, hence the -E flag):

```
sed -i '' -E 's,@critical[^{]*{\s*((.|\s)*)[^}]*},\1,g' style.css
```

Effectively I'm trying to replace the entire @critical rule with only its content (match group 1). The regex `critical[^{]*{\s*((.|\s)*)[^}]*}` itself works perfectly when I plug it into [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4tfgn) but I can’t seem to get it to work in the context of the above `sed` command. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much in advance.

—————

**Edit:**

**I have since learned that `sed` doesn’t support multiline regex which would explain the problem I’m encountering. While minifying the CSS (effectively turning it into a single line of text) makes it work under `sed`, I’d still appreciate someone pointing me towards a solution that works across a non-minified multiline CSS file (perl? awk?).**

Comment: Why is people downvoting? Its a legitimate question. Come on!

Comment: Can you add some samples of the properties instead of the ... ?

Comment: @Matias Barrios in the meanwhile i have learned that sed doesn’t seem to support multiline regex. this seems to be the cause of error because when i minify the css (effectively turning it into a single line) it works as intended. i’d still prefer a solution that doesn’t require minifying the css for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe 's,\@critical[^{]*{\s*((.|\s)*)[^}]*},$1,g' style.css
```

Then `style.css` will look like:

```
.foo {
        ...
    }

    @media bar {
        ...
    }
```

- The `-0777` switch tells `perl` to slurp all lines at once, which
  makes the regex match over multiple lines.
- The `-i.bak` option enables an in-place file editing keeping the backup
  file with `.bak` extension. If no backup is needed, just put `-i`.
- The regex inside is almost identical to yours except for a backslash
  before the at-mark. Otherwise `perl` tries to interpret it as an array variable name. Another change is the `$1` instead of `\1` in the replacement. This is also the `perl`'s requirement.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it, is there any book you could lemme know which has perl one liners kind of, I tried to google but mostly have deep in perl, right now I am looking for one liners only from basics, if anything you could share will be grateful to you, cheers :)

Comment: How about a page [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Perlorama/perl_one_liners.shtml) or a book [here](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=bgYvDwAAQBAJ). `Perl` has so many command-line options that I imagine there will be nobody in the world who have tried all of them (except for Larry Wall and Tom Christiansen). Cheers!

Comment: Woww, cool. Thank you lemme go through it thanks a TON for letting know here.